# Key-space analysis of an algorithm

Tags: matlab, floating-point, key, precision

I have an algorithm that requires a set of keys to encrypt a text (image of size N x N). It is an image encryption algorithm for a project. The key can be thought of as a tuple

```
x_0, lambda, d, i, j, DF, U
```

where:

- `0 < x_0 < 1`;
- `3.57 <= lambda <= 4`,
- `15 < d < inf`, `1 < i < inf`, `1< j < inf`
- `1E8 < DF < 1E9`
- `U` is any random 4 x 4 matrix.

If this is my parameter set, how can I calculate the key-space of the algorithm?

Comment: What is the algorithm name?

Comment: Which parameter is the input text?

Comment: I have added the text

Comment: Possibly better fit for [crypto.se] or [security.se].

Comment: okay, i will post it there

Comment: Could you mention the type of each parameter (double, float, int ?).